# Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in \installer\adapter\template.php on line 81

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

When trying to find and zainstalirovat through the "Extensions Manager" I created a template, and when click "Install", then an error:

`"Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in Z:\home\website.joomla\www\libraries\cms\installer\adapter\template.php on line 81"`

Who knows what to do, help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a problem in `templateDetails.xml` file.

From looking at the source of [template adapter](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/installer/adapter/template.php) seems that you didn't specify **extension client** attribute (whether template should install for site or administration).

```
<extension version="3.1" type="template" client="site">
```